# makefile: how to call macros in macros

Tags: linux, unix, makefile

I have the following macros in my make file:

---

pdf:
  // do something

clean:
  // just another fancy thing

---

No I want to declare a macro all: which include (or call) the macros above. The following thing doesn't work:

---

all:
  pdf: 
  clean:

---

I don't want to repeat the code from pdf: and clean: in order not to rebel against DRY principle.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Downvoted because the example code does not use Makefile macros. Improper usage of term has directed search engines to this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not macros, they are targets.

Makefiles take the syntax of [target]: [dependent target 1] [dependent target 2]

Try:

```
all: pdf clean
```

Comment: Thanks theatrus, I think I must learn at least the basics of makefile.

Answer (score 1):

> executing make without argument is
>   same as calling make all.

That's not correct.  The first normal target in the file is the default target.  There's nothing magical about **all**, though it is conventional to use that as the first target.

Comment: "it is conventional to use that as the first target" - with myown makefiles, I prefer to have that be `help`, which echoes the makefile's options to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You also can run:

```
make clean pdf
```

Any way, **all** is commonly used as a default make target - in other words executing make without argument is same as calling *make all*. This maybe very confusing for expirienced users, therefore if you want "such a shortcut", call it deferently (e.g. *cpdf*)

Comment: Thanks idimba for this shortcut idea!